# Changing woocommerce price based on product attribute, if product has attribute change it, else do something else

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, rounding

I'm using

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'custom_calculated_total' );
    function custom_calculated_total( $total ) {
    
    $total = round( $total, -2 );
    return $total;
    }
```

to round the price of products.
The issue i have is that i'd like to implement rounding only to products that have certain attribute not to my entire shop. Is this even possible and how ?

Tried a lot of combinations and none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it do what I wanted

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'custom_calculated_total', 10, 2);

function custom_calculated_total($price, $product)
{
    $check = $product->get_attribute('state');

    if($check == 'import') {
        $price = round($price, -2);
    }

    return $price;
}
```